# loop over rows of a data.frame and use them as input for a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops, lapply

The `input` values (`a` and `b`) for my `foo()` function come from a `expand.grid()` call.

I was wondering how to loop over the rows of `input` data.frame such that at each round, one `a` and `b` from one row of `input` data.frame is used in `foo()` as a named `list`?

```
foo <- function(a, b) { 
  b-a
  }

input <- rev(expand.grid(b=1:4,a=1:4))

#   a b
#1  1 1  # at round one, `a = 1`, `b = 1`
#2  1 2
#3  1 3
#4  1 4  # at round four, `a = 1`, `b = 4`
#.  . .
#.  . .
#.  . .

foo(a=, b=)

# Desired output:

[[1]] `a=1, b=1` 
     [1]  0

[[2]] `a=1, b=2`
     [1]   1
# .
# .
# .
```

Comment: You don't need to do that,you would say  `foo(input$a, input$b) ` and  R will automatically do it for all rows and return a vector of the same length as a and b.

Comment: @Elin, I was wondering if I could get a `list` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `foo` function is more complicated than just `b-a` you can use `Map`.

```
Map(foo, input$a, input$b)
```

Comment: What if I need a `data.frame` output instead of a `list` output?

Comment: `data.frame(a = mapply(foo, input$a, input$b))`

Comment: It depends on how the actual function `foo` is written.